# Django Celery, App import error only on production

Tags: django, django-celery

I have a file structure like this:

- myapp

  - artist_applications

    - tasks.py
  - tasks

    - celery.py

```
# settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myapp.artist_application',
    ...
```

```
# celery.py
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings.production')
app = Celery("tasks")
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

```
# tasks.py

from tasks.celery import app as celery_myapp
from django.apps import apps
from django.conf import settings
import requests


@celery_esns.task(name='sample_task')
def sample_task():
    print('TESTING CELERY')

@celery_esns.task(name='publish_artist_task')
def publish_artist_task(payload, artist_id):
    r = requests.post(settings.PUBLISH_URL, json = payload)

    if r.status_code == 200:
        apps.get_model('artist_application', 'Artist').objects.filter(unique_id=artist_id).update(published=True)
    else:
        raise Exception("Error publishing artist with id: " + artist_id)
```

On development all is running fine when I start Celery with:

```
celery -A myapp.tasks worker -Q celery -l info
```

But on production I run the command (in a virtualenv) and I get the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'artist_application'. Check that 'myapp.artist_application.apps.ArtistApplication.name' is correct.
```

Any ideas where to look? I don't get how 'runserver' is loading the apps differently then wsgi?

Comment: Try to import the Artist model directly into your tasks.py and update. If your publish_artist_task function is getting called.

Answer (score 1):

I had to put the full dotted path in apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ArtistApplicationConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp.artist_application'
    verbose_name = "Artist Application"
```